# "Can't use nil for keys or values on PFObject. Use NSNull for values"というエラー

Tags: ios, swift

Parseを使用しながらチャットアプリを作っているのですが、下記のようなエラーがでます。
"Can't use nil for keys or values on PFObject. Use NSNull for values."
こちらはどのようなエラーのことを言っているのか、ご経験のある方解決策を教えてくださいませ。

Answer (score 1):

エラーが発生したのであれば、エラーメッセージが差している付近のコードを載せられた方が多くの解答を期待できると思います。

で、Parseは使わないので、リファレンスからの推定ですが、`setObject(_:forKey:)`系のメソッドでエラーが発生したのだと思われます。これは、Foundation内のApple提供のコレクションクラスにも共通しているのですが、**nilをキーや値にすることはできません**。Parseにも同じ制約があることがリファレンスに明記されています。
[-setObject:forKey:](https://parse.com/docs/ios/api/Classes/PFObject.html#/c:objc(cs)PFObject(im)setObject:forKey:)
コードがないのでわからないのですが、keyの方がnilなら大抵ロジックエラーですので、エラー発生行以前の部分を再チェック、objectの方でしたら、「意図的にnilを代入しようとしているのか」どうかを判断して、意図に反する状態なら当然それ以前の部分をデバッグ、nilを入れたいのなら、それはできないので、メッセージに示されたように「nilの代わりになる値」として、NSNull(のインスタンス)を使用するように修正してください。

上の説明が当てはまらないような全然別のメソッドで出たエラーであれば、お知らせください。
(ご自分で書いたコードの中には、`setObject(_:forKey:)`がなくても、フレームワークの中で暗黙的に呼ばれている、と言った可能性もあります。)

Comment: コメントありがとうございます。大変助かります。どこのコードでエラーが出ているのか分からず、textFieldに文字を入力しSubmitボタンを押した後に、アプリがクラッシュしてしまいます。その後に出るエラーなのですが、デバックエリアには下記のように記載されております。
2016-02-07 08:14:52.400 /アプリネーム/[1070:34015] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'Can't use nil for keys or values on PFObject. Use NSNull for values.'
*** First throw call stack:
またAppDelegate.swiftファイルの部分で
import UIKit
import Parse
@UIApplicationMain
class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate {
class行の右側のエラーに、Thread1: signal SIGABRT
と出ました。

Comment: ご連絡ありがとうございます。今回の場合Parseのランタイムが意図的に投げた例外が原因なので、その場合のエラーは何でもAppDelegateに表示されてしまうようで、場所はあてになりません。First throw call stackの中身にはバグ解析に必要な情報が含まれていると思いますが、今回の場合、データにnilがあるのが原因なので、それがあっても原因にたどり着くのは難しいかもしれません。とりあえずSubmit処理時にParseのオブジェクト内に保持されることになるデータ(通常は使わないけど一応値が参照されるテキストフィールドとかはありませんか?)をひたすら全部チェックして、中身がnilになっていないか確かめてもらわないと仕方ないかもしれないです。

Comment: Le Pere d'OOさん、早速のご連絡ありがとうございます。お陰様で上記のアドバイスがエラー箇所の特定につながり解決しました。ありがとうございます。また新たなエラーが出ましたがw調べてから解決できなかった場合には再度投稿いたします。

Comment: お役に立てたのなら大変嬉しいです。「エラーメッセージが差している付近のコードを載せられた方が」とか書いた直後に「場所はあてになりません」とかろくに説明もせず書いてしまって少し反省していたところです。Swiftの絡んだ実行時エラーはバージョンによっても細かく出方が変わるので、実際に見てみるまで何とも言えない、のが正直なところです。エラーにかかわる質問を書く必要が出たら、「少し多め」くらいを意識して情報を盛り込んでおいた方が、早く有用な回答にたどり着けると思います。うまく活用していってください。

Comment: とんでもございません。またご連絡が遅くなりまして申し訳ございません。また今後とも何かアドバイスをいただきますととても嬉しいです。よろしくお願い申し上げます。